CORS issue in .net 8 web api with nginx
I have a .net 8 web api project running on ubuntu machine (AWS). I have configured nginx server configured with cors policy. So here nginx receives the request and redirect to port 5000 where actual .net app is running.
Problem: I am getting CORS error. Do I need to fix in .net app (Program.cs) or It need to be fix in nginx server configuration?
here is my nginx config:
enter code here

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/school-api;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # Include client's IP address in the 
                                      request
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    # Handle OPTIONS requests for CORS preflight
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If- 
            Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

    # Handle POST and GET requests
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    
}

}


server {

root /var/www/school-api;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name api.mithilaschool.com; # managed by Certbot


location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # Include client's IP address in the 
                request
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    # Handle OPTIONS requests for CORS preflight
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified- 
           Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' always;
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
        return 204;
    }

    # Handle POST and GET requests
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    
    
}



listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mithilaschool.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
                                                     Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mithilaschool.com/privkey.pem; # managed by 
            Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
if ($host = api.mithilaschool.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
server_name api.mithilaschool.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


I do not have experience first hand with .net8 but in this experience with Django/Python, Node/Express...it is in almost any instance I have seen a framework setting to set, not an nginx config...does this walk you in the right direction? https://code-maze.com/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/
